# ignite rebalance can be done if partitions cache was in LOST state

Tags: ignite

our cache partitions was in LOST state, so does the rebalance process can be done for this cache in this case? do we have to reset lost partition before rebalance process can be trigger? (we use version 2.15 of ignite)

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms, you would need to "reset lost partitions" before your cache was fully usable.

Comment: Can I let rebalance process done before reset lost part? our cluster ignite was in high load with large data rebalance,and I saw that reset  lost part seem to impact to workload, maybe it cause OOM and restart again :(

Comment: The data rebalance will be far more expensive than resetting lost partitions. On a memory-only cluster, resetting lost partitions just says, "I know I've lost some data." So, sure, you can wait to reset your lost partitions, but any client application will return exceptions if you access those lost partitions.

Comment: Aggree with you, rebalance so terrible, our cluster take approximately 2 days to   finish rebalance process (with 1T data per Node/5 Node)
any, tks for support, I already finished testing and confirmed that rebalance process can be done even though partitions was  in LOST state

Comment: Two days to rebalance isn’t normal. There’s something else going on.